# Fetching data from an API works locally but not live

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, netlify

First time building a site with Nuxt.js and I'm requesting data from an API that works great locally but when I access the site through Netlify, none of the code seems to run. I'm assuming this has something to do with my misunderstanding of how static sites work.

What I'm trying to do is check if there is a browser cookie, if not create one and fetch the API to get the user's general location and check their city against an array of cities in NY.  If there is a match then close the v-banner.  If there is already a browser cookie then close the v-banner.

Abridged index.vue:

```
<template>
    <v-app v-bind:class="{ alertOpen: alertOpen }">
        <v-main>
            <v-banner
                class="state-alert"
                transition="slide-y-transition"
                v-bind:class="{ alertOpen: alertOpen }"
            >
                By our calculations, it looks like you might be visiting our website from outside of New York. Unfortunately at this time, we can't sell our Granola outside of New York. If you are buying a gift for someone with a New York address then please proceed.
                <template>
                    <v-btn
                        icon
                        color="alert"
                        v-on:click="alertOpen = false"
                    >
                        <v-icon>mdi-close</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                </template>
            </v-banner>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
    let nyList = ['Albany', 'Amsterdam', 'Auburn', 'Batavia', 'Beacon', 'Binghamton', 'Buffalo', 'Canandaigua', 'Cohoes', 'Corning', 'Cortland', 'Dunkirk', 'Elmira', 'Fulton', 'Geneva', 'Glen Cove', 'Glens Falls', 'Gloversville', 'Hornell', 'Hudson', 'Ithaca', 'Jamestown', 'Johnstown', 'Kingston', 'Lackawanna', 'Little Falls', 'Lockport', 'Long Beach', 'Mechanicville', 'Middletown', 'Mount Vernon', 'New Rochelle', 'New York', 'Newburgh', 'Niagara Falls', 'North Tonawanda', 'Norwich', 'Ogdensburg', 'Olean', 'Oneida', 'Oneonta', 'Oswego', 'Peekskill', 'Plattsburgh', 'Port Jervis', 'Poughkeepsie', 'Rensselaer', 'Rochester', 'Rome', 'Rye', 'Salamanca', 'Saratoga Springs', 'Schenectady', 'Sherrill', 'Syracuse', 'Tonawanda', 'Troy', 'Utica', 'Watertown', 'Watervliet', 'White Plains', 'Yonkers'];

    export default ({
        head() {
            return {
                script: [{
                    body: true
                }]
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                geoData: [],
                alertOpen: true
            }
        },
        async fetch() {
            const locationCookie = this.$cookies.get('location-cookie');

            if(!locationCookie) {
                console.log('no cookie');
                this.$cookies.set('location-cookie', 'true', {
                    path: '/',
                    maxAge: 31556952
                });
                this.geoData = await fetch(
                    'https://ipgeolocation.abstractapi.com/v1/?api_key=1eef312cdda9428cac26815c9d3bdd26'
                ).then(res => res.json());

                var vm = this;
                compareCity(this.geoData.city);

                function compareCity(city) {
                    var i;
                    for(i = 0; i < nyList.length; i++) {
                        if(nyList[i].toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '') == city.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '')) {
                            console.log(city);
                            vm.alertOpen = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                console.log('yes cookie');
                this.alertOpen = false;
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Not sure if ya'll also need to see the nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
    mode: "universal",

    // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
    head: {
        title: 'homemade-crunch',
        meta: [
            { charset: 'utf-8' },
            { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
            { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
        ],
        link: [
            { rel: "preconnect", href: "https://app.snipcart.com" },
            { rel: "preconnect", href: "https://cdn.snipcart.com" },
            { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0.23/default/snipcart.css', defer: true },
            { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&family=Open+Sans&display=swap' }
        ],
        script: [
            { src: "https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/v3.0/default/snipcart.js", defer: true }
        ]
    },

    // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
    css: [
    ],

    // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
    plugins: [
        '@plugins/vuetify'
    ],

    // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
    components: true,

    // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
    buildModules: [],

    // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
    modules: [
        'vue-scrollto/nuxt',
        'cookie-universal-nuxt'
    ],

    // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
    build: {
    },

    server: {
        port: 3333,
        host: '0.0.0.0'
    }
}
```

The git repo: https://github.com/mat148/Homemade-crunch
and live site: https://www.homemadecrunch.com/

Let me know if I've forgotten something or done something silly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to move my logic from the index.vue to a javascript file